# Convert MKMapRect to CLRegion

Tags: ios, gps, mkmapview, mkmaprect

How can I convert the visible rect of a map view into a CLRegion for use with CLGeocoder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I just found this answer here:
https://gist.github.com/3402711

Comment: any idea on how to do the opposite (CLRegion to MKMapRect)?